# Python Error : list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I programmed a battleship game in python. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""Battleship: Command Line Python Game

This is a classical version of the battleship game.

There is a board in which a battleship is randomly placed in a spot. User who correctly guesses the spot wins the game.

User have eight turns to guess correct cordinates

The game is coded in python 2"""

#imports randint from random to generate random numbers
from random import randint

#creating the board
board = []

#Filling up the board
for x in range(5):
  board.append(["O"] * 6)

#Function to print out the board to user
def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print " ".join(row)

#Call to print board to user
print_board(board)

#Function to generate random battleship row
def random_row(board):
  return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

#Function to generate random battleship coloumn
def random_col(board):
  return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

#Call to generate random row and coloumn
ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

#Snippet for debugging
print ship_row
print ship_col
#Snippet for debugging

#Running Turns
for turn in range(8):

  #Print out turn number to user
  print "Turn: " + str(turn + 1)

  #Accepts users guess
  guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row: "))
  guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col: "))

  #Check if correct guess
  if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
    #Congratulate the guess
    print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
    #Exit loop and Game Over
    print "Game Over"
    break

  #If not correct guess
  else:

    #Check weather input is valid
    if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 5) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 5):
      #Inform an invalid input
      print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."

    #Check weather repeated guess
    elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'X'):
      #Inform a repeated guess
      print "You guessed that one already."

    #For valid new input
    else:
      #Inform a missed shot
      print "You missed my battleship!"
      #Fill guessed place with X and print out the board
      board[guess_row][guess_col] = 'X'
      print_board(board)

    #Check Weather out of Turns
    if turn == 7:
      #GAME OVER
      print "Game Over"
```

It seems to show error:
This is the full description of the error from the terminal:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prem59/Dropbox/Python/Codecademy/battleship.py", line 77, in 
    if(board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'X'):
IndexError: list index out of range

I think the elif statement is causing trouble. But if I remove it, I will not be able to check whether the user entered a repetitive input. How can I fix this problem without affecting the functionality of the program?

Comment: Look at the code where you create your board. What are its dimensions? (Hint: What does `range(5)` return?)

Comment: `range(5)` will give you `[0,1,2,3,4]`. so you should either change it to `range(6)` or change the validity check

Comment: Thanks. Now I fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in range(5):
  board.append(["O"] * 6)
```

Notice that this `for` loop gives you a 5x6 (5 rows x 6 columns) board. However,

```
if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 5) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 5):
    ...
elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'X'):
    ...
```

With inputs `(5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3)...` This gets evaluated to the `elif` block, because `5 > 5` is `False`.

```
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
X X X X X X
```

The inputs `(5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3)...` are that X row which your board doesn't have.

***Quick Fix:***

```
# Just add another row, the X row, and you're allset
for x in range(6):
      board.append(["O"] * 6)

# Check if the input == 5, print "not in the ocean", because it really is not.
if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row >= 5)
```

By the way, it's a better practice to have a constant variable at the top of your program.

```
SIZE = 6
GUESSES = 8
```

And refer to them whenever relevant. That way, it's easier to change your board size or number of guesses in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your board is currently of size `5x6`.

This means the row/column indexes are: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

Your current condition to check if the guess is off the board is:

```
if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 5) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 5):
```

but this allows index `5` for both rows and columns when the maximum is `4`.

So you should correct it to:

```
if guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 5 or guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4:
```

*(the parenthesis are unnecessary)*

---

Note that this is entirely personal preference, but I would consider the following more readable:

```
if not (0 <= guess_row < 5 and 0 <= guess_col < 5):
```